# Restore a deleted Perforce client

Tags: perforce

If I accidentally deleted a client with command "p4 client -d ". Is there any way to restore it? Or at least see the client spec (root folder path, view, host, etc...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Perforce knowledge base has an [article](http://kb.perforce.com/article/803/recovering-a-deleted-workspace) on this. It sounds like it will probably need some co-operation from your Perforce admin. :-(

Answer (score 2):

If you have a spec depot, then all client specs are stored there with all their versions. If you delete a client, you can always retrieve the client spec of "yesterday" or whatever previous version you want.
Otherwise, no you can't get it.